# Node.JS - Cannot read property 'ColorType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a little issue with "Enums" in Node.js at the moment.

I currently have a file called 'colorHandler.js' in my lib/ folder, and I'm accessing it in another file in my /lib. the format in chatHandler.js is as followed:

```
var format = {
    GREEN: {irc: '\u000309', mc: 'a'},
    RED: {irc: '\u000304', mc: 'c'},
}
```

And in my IRC Handler, I currently have just one declaration (after requiring, of course) that looks lik this:

```
Command.test = function(ocmd) {
    client.say(to, c.format.GREEN.irc. + from + ': '+ c.format.RED.irc +'Command handler works!');
}
```

The error I am recieving in my debugger is:
    "message": "uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'GREEN' of undefined"

What is going on here, it use to work for me, now it's just constantly throwing the error once the 'test' command is typed in chat.

Comment: format is not accessible outside colorHandler.js as nodejs add wrapper function to each file.  What is c in second file

Comment: c is `var c = require('../lib/colorHandler.js');` - For now 'c' is just used as a test, until I come up with a better name :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var format` to `module.exports.format`

```
module.exports.format = {
    GREEN: {irc: '\u000309', mc: 'a'},
    RED: {irc: '\u000304', mc: 'c'},
}
```

when you use require(...) it become

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  module.exports.format = {
    GREEN: {irc: '\u000309', mc: 'a'},
    RED: {irc: '\u000304', mc: 'c'},
  }
});
```

Comment: That did it, cheers! I'm now on the harder part of my task after this. Hopefully I don't need to come back here, even though this site is wonderful. :P You know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your object with `module.exports.format = format`.

When writing a node module, only the attributes defined on `module.exports` or `exports` will be exposed. You can then `require` the module and access the exposed attributes in another node module.

Your code should look like

```
var format = {
    GREEN: {irc: '\u000309', mc: 'a'},
    RED: {irc: '\u000304', mc: 'c'},
};

module.exports.format = format;
```

Comment: Returns the same error. `"message": "uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'GREEN' of undefined"` (using Winston debugging)

Comment: It shouldn't... Are you certain?